Protect-On-Edit
I'm currently working on writing a script in Google Apps Script to protect cells on edits made by users other than the owner.
Here's the code I tried:
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range
    var me = Session.getActiveUser()
    range.setNote('Last Modified: ' + new Date() + '\n' + me)
    var effectiveUser = Session.getEffectiveUser()
    var protection = range.protect()
    protection.removeEditor(me)
    protection.removeEditor(effectiveUser)
    protection.setDomainEdit(false)
}

Ideally, this is supposed to protect whatever cell or cells are edited by the user.
This works, but is incredibly inconsistent, and the user is still able to edit the protected cell after waiting for a few seconds. If the user is fast enough, they can keep making changes before the script kicks in, if at all. Is this a code issue, or is it just rooted in the speed at which the API is called?

There is a code issue and a performance issue.
Simple triggers, including onEdit, have authorization and limits that functions run by other means don't have. On the other hand, calls to Google Apps Script services like SpreadsheetApp are slower than some users' ability to edit multiple cells.
Also, users can't remove themselves as editors.
One effective solution to part of the problem is to utilize an installable trigger, which can provide more control and flexibility in your script's execution.
To solve the overall problem, consider using other means to get user input, like using a dialog, sidebar, or web app, instead of asking users to enter data on the cells directly, which should not be edited by them after they get input.
